# General sum-to-product trigonometric formula for interfering waves?

Tags: trigonometry

I see many related posts, but none speaks about the general formula.

Consider the sum of 2 waves of arbitrary frequency, phase and amplitude. Without loss of generality, we can set the first wave as a "reference" to reduce the number of parameters to 3 degrees of freedom. Then the question is what would be its modulated-wave / waves-product form (if it indeed exists):

$$\cos(t)+A\cos(\omega t+\phi)=A_1\big(1+A_2\cos(\omega_1t+\phi_1)\big)\cos(\omega_2 t+\phi_2)$$

What are $A_i, \omega_i, \phi_i$, $i=1,2$ and is there a way to get them straightforwardly (or a way to see the problem that makes it simpler)?

Comment: @Micah that works for $\omega=1$

Comment: This is one of the 3 special cases with 2 degrees of freedom.

Comment: If the $\omega$s are not relatively prime it sounds difficult to do with linear transforms.

Comment: Can you develop? what does it means for 2 quantities to be relatively prime? Do you mean commensurable? If this is the case, we can reasonably make this assumption since rational numbers are dense in real numbers (continued fraction...etc).